# Is there a way to return to my activity which calls the activation of a device-admin?

Tags: android, android-activity, device-admin

I need to enable a device-admin for my app, it's working like this called from Activity A:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,    deviceAdminComponentName);
intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Your boss told you to do this");
startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

but i want that after my activity A calls the device-admin-activation prompt and the user says activate, immediately  return to the caller-activation. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just try if it works..

In your DeviceAdminReceiver's onEnabled() method start the activity that you want to show after device admin activates.